# for loop inside onBindView Holder iterates 4 times on every cycle

Tags: android, for-loop, android-recyclerview

I am using a for loop inside onBindView Holder of recyclerView adapter ,but it iterates 4 times for a single cycle .Below are the details of my code Any help would be greatly appreciated. ex

**My recycler view code**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.online_recy);
        final GridLayoutManager gm = new GridLayoutManager(Online3.this, 2);
        recyclerView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        final OnlineAdapter oa = new OnlineAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list2,wishList);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(gm);
        recyclerView2.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
        oa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(oa);
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class OnlineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OnlineAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Online2_G_S> online2_g_sList = null;
View itemView;
List wishList;



public OnlineAdapter(Context context, List<Online2_G_S> list, List wishList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.online2_g_sList = list;
    this.wishList = wishList;
}


@Override
public OnlineAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.online_shopping_single_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final OnlineAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    for (int n=0 ;n<4;n++){

                Log.i("sandeep", String.valueOf(wishList.get(n)));//liked
            }
}
```

and the logs are

```
    09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
09-18 11:01:51.811 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.811 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.811 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.811 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
09-18 11:01:51.823 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.823 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.824 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.824 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
09-18 11:01:51.843 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.843 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.843 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.843 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
09-18 11:01:51.857 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.857 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.857 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.857 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
```

my expected results are

```
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 0
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 1
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 2
09-18 11:01:51.777 27865-27865/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sandeep: 3
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want my expected results ie 0 1 2 3

Comment: Post some more code on how you initialised the adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for (int n=0 ;n<4;n++){
    Log.i("sandeep", String.valueOf(n));//liked
}
```

to

```
Log.i("sandeep", String.valueOf(n));//liked
```

You should do in the `onBindViewHolder` method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.i("sandeep", String.valueOf(position));//liked
}
```

It will go through the data . And `position` will be changed .

If the size of your `online2_g_sList` is 4,and `onBindViewHolder` method will go 
through the data for 4 times .

And

- if `position == 0` ,if will loop for first time.
- if `position == 1` ,if will loop for second time.
- if `position == 2` ,if will loop for third time.
- if `position == 3` ,if will loop for fourth time.

So if if you want to loop ,you can change the `n` to `1` in your code .

Comment: But I want to use for loop

Comment: If you want to loop in your code , you must change the `n` to `1`.

Comment: I have edited my code , i want wishList  list  items using for loop

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` also loop .@dhami_ji

Comment: @KeiLiuyue Thanks i got it